# Mac Reset Password Isn't Working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

It's very often that I have to reset my Mac password using recovery mode as I keep using fingerprint to login. If I shut down my computer after prolonged use of fingerprint, the machine asks for a password which I remember, but the machine will not take it.

So I have to reset the password either from Apple ID way or from Recovery Mode Reset Password. But this time, nothing is working and my machine isn't updating the password which I'm changing as I keep seeing the old password hint even though I changed it to something else. I have even tried to reinstall OS hoping this will work but it didn't.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hello, just to make sure, you selected the correct drive in Recovery Mode after typing ```resetpassword```?

Comment: So problem was with my Key Manager. I've to reset my machine to factory settings to sort the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify your keyboard is set to the correct language?
Many "wrong password" inputs come from non-english keyboard layouts, e.g. z and y are switched on german keyboards, usually not a problem, but in recovery or single user mode the OS only understands english if not set otherwise.